# Stop API path auto decode in web config file

Tags: node.js, web-services, iis, web-config, decode

I have a node js server that deployed on the azure app service.
Before deployment, my encoded API path {project/test%2Fxyz} works on the local server, the encoding is needed.

But after deploying to the azure app service, the API path will be decoded to {project/test/xyz}, which gets the server to return 404...

So my question is: does anyone know how to disable this auto decode in webconfig file? Many thanks if you can provide an example.

Comment: Usually, after deploying to the server, the API path will not be automatically decoded. Is your API path in the requested url? please post more details information about your requirement.